# Data -id content inside of tooltip

Tags: javascript

I need to get content from a data-content-id inside of a tooltip. For some reason it doesn´t grab the content and pull it inside.

Here is the code:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 /// Grab all elements with the class "hasTooltip"
$('.hasTooltip').each(function() { // Notice the .each() loop, discussed below
$(this).qtip({
    content: {
        text: $('#tooltip-content-' + $(this).find('[data-contentid]').data('contentid')) // Grab content using data-content-id attribite value
    }
});
});
});
```

For better understanding here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6yq3/465/ where you can see, that i can´t get the "CONTENTEXAMPLE" inside of the tooltip.

Comment: That would be jquery, not plain [javascript] as the tag suggests ... you can just set somenode.title="your tooltip text" (or title="your tooltip text" in the html tag) to get a "tooltip" on most browsers which is easy to retrieve without jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `text` accepts a function so try:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    /// Grab all elements with the class "hasTooltip"
    $('.hasTooltip').each(function () { // Notice the .each() loop, discussed below
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: function () {
                    return $(this).next('[data-contentid]').data('contentid'); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEgRp/)**

or rather this way:(I dont understand your html structure)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzXqF/)**

Comment: I tried this, now not even the empty tooltips is shown. http://jsfiddle.net/L6yq3/469/

Comment: @user2800148 just remove a slas in that. it was a typo http://jsfiddle.net/eEgRp/

Comment: I think the problem is in the html structure as you wrote. I want to have the "CONTENTEXAMPLE" inside of the tooltip. For that i set the <div class="pageContent" data-contentid="test">CONTENTEXAMPLE</div>. Your second solution works so far, but why it doesn´t work with the data-contentid="test"?

Comment: @user2800148 it works see my updated fiddle. There was a syntax error. I just took the html structure from your fiddle. There you dont have the element `#tooltip-content-test` etc